# HTML table row vertical struts *shorter* than the row height

Tags: html, css, xhtml

How can you get table row vertical struts (shorter than the row height), or partial table cell borders, or table row bottom/top margins, like this? :

[image: vertical white struts are SHORTER than the row height]

This is what I got from the graphic designer; as you can see the table row background (dark or transparent) is somewhat out of sync with the rows themselves so don't cling to that too much (background is irrelevant here).

The key, however, is that the **vertical white struts must be shorter than the row height**.

One idea that comes to my mind is to insert dummy rows to the HTML table, but it sucks doesn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
border-spacing: 10px; /* or whatever your require */
border-collapse: separate;
```

On your table element

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/gLChh/1/)

Sample HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Sample CSS

```
table {
    background:teal;
    border-spacing: 10px;
    border-collapse: separate;
}
td {
    border-left:1px solid white;
    padding:0 20px;
}
td:first-child{
    border-left:none;
}
```

---

### [Alternatively..](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/gLChh/)

You can use the `:before` pseudo element:

```
table {
    background:teal;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
td {
    padding:10px 20px;
    position:relative;
}
tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background:grey;
}
td:before {
    content:'';
    border-left:1px solid white;
    height:50%;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:25%;
}
td:first-child:before {
    border:none;
}
```

Comment: Ok, perhaps I wasn't precise. Your solution almost works, but what if you want to use different background colors for odd/even rows? What we get is vertical space between the rows, and the bg color there is the table background color. http://jsfiddle.net/eGpES/2/ Ideally each of the rows would get taller (like +10px at the top and +10px at the bottom, with the white struts vertically centered).

Comment: Looks great, except that it doesn't work in Icedove... when I change the border color to green I can see it on the left side of the JSFiddle Result window. :(

Comment: Iceweasel, I mean. Nevertheless I accept, thanks SW4.